# Unable to boot SunOS 5.8

Tags: boot, solaris, fsck

I had to hard reboot a SunOS 5.8 server due to a networking fault. On giving 'boot' command on OK prompt, I get the following messages

Can't read disk label. Can't open disk label package Boot device: secondary File and args: Can't read disk label. Can't open disk label package

Can't open boot device

I am unable to run fsck on OK prompt. How should I go about troubleshooting this error?

Its a Sun Enterprise E3500 running SunOS 5.8

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Does it have a local system disk, or is it supposed to boot from SAN or over the network? The messages look like the system disk (and possibly the secondary system disk) might have failed, or the system might just have lost its firmware settings.

This server model was available as new from April 1998 to April 2003. Right now, your server must be at least 20 years old! It is an unfortunate fact of life that old hard disks that have been years and years in continuous use will often not start up again once stopped for any reason. Based on the system's age, I think disk failure is the most likely cause for your problem. I *really* hope your backups are up to date...

The OK prompt is the rough functional equivalent of BIOS settings of PC hardware, and is also known as the *OpenBoot prompt*. SunOS 5.8 is also better known as *Solaris 8*.

The nice thing about old servers such as this is that the troubleshooting procedures are usually very well documented compared to PC hardware. Download the [System Reference Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19095-01/ent35.srvr/805-2630-11/805-2630-11.pdf) and start working through chapter 9.5: *Diagnosing Problems*. Since the system is not booting, you must skip sub-chapter 9.5.2 as not applicable, and go on to 9.5.3. It describes a few commands you can use in the OK prompt:

- `printenv` will display the system configuration settings, including the configured boot target(s).
- `show-devs`, `probe-scsi-all` and/or `probe-fcal-all` will show you which disks and other devices the firmware can detect. (If the system is supposed to use a local system disk, but cannot detect any disks, that means the system disk is dead.)

In chapter 10.2. there is also a diagnostic flowchart for "System Cannot Boot".

If the system disk(s) are not obviously dead, you might want to boot from an external Solaris 8/SPARC boot media to evaluate the status of the system disks further.

Comment: Hi @telcoM, Thanks for taking time to show me a way. printenv has listed the system configuration settings. I could see values next to boot-device but boot-file seems to be blank. 

I could also boot to single user mode on CDROM. I get 'WARNING: Device ssd1 failed to power up.' and 'WARNING: Device ssd2 failed to power up.', while booting from the CDROM.

Comment: `ssd1` and `ssd2` would seem to refer to the disks. Unfortunately, those warnings might mean you have not one but two dead disks in the system. And when a disk "fails to power up", it means it is not communicating with the rest of the system at all, so it cannot be fixed by software.